# Cannot connect to my MiniKube external service ip/port?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have a mongo yaml and web-app(NodeJS) yaml set up like this:

mongo-config.yaml

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongo-config
data:
  mongo-url: mongo-service
```

mongo-secret.yaml

```
   apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mongo-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  mongo-user: bW9uZ291c2Vy
  mongo-password: bW9uZ29wYXNzd29yZA==
```

mongo.yaml

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
      # blueprint for pods, creates pods with mongo:5.0 image
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongodb
          image: mongo:5.0
          ports:
          - containerPort: 27017
          env:
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mongo-secret
                key: mongo-user
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mongo-secret
                key: mongo-password
---
# kind: service
# name: any
# selector: select pods to forward the requests to
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 27017
```

and the webapp.yaml:

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapp-deployment
  labels:
    app: webapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webapp
      # blueprint for pods, creates pods with mongo:5.0 image
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: webapp
          image: nanajanashia/k8s-demo-app:v1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          env:
            - name: USER_NAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongo-secret
                  key: mongo-user
            - name: USER_PWD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongo-secret
                  key: mongo-password
            - name: DB_URL
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: mongo-config
                  key: mongo-url
---
# kind: service
# name: any
# selector: select pods to forward the requests to
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webapp-service
spec:
  # default ClusterIP
  # nodeport = external service
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: webapp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 30100
```

I ran the commands for each file
kubectl apply -f
i checked the status of the webapp which returned:
app listening on port 3000!
I got the IP address by
minikube ip

and the port was 30100
Why cannot not I access this web app?
I get a site cant be reached error.

Comment: You are saying you cannot access this web app. How are you accessing it? What happens? Timeout, error?

Comment: through the web browser, just timeout.

Comment: Can you please provide the output of following commands 1. `Kubectl get services`  2. `minikube service --url <service-name>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac, check your minikube driver. I had to stop, delete minikube, then restart while specifying the hyperkit driver like so.

```
minikube stop
minikube delete

docker start --vm-driver=hyperkit
```

The information listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60710171/minikube-ip-is-not-reachable) is pretty useful too.

Answer (score 0):

I was also following the same tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_o8dwzRlu4) and this helped me. Posting it for future readers.

```
minikube service --url <name of the web service>
```

In my case it is

```
minikube service --url web-service
```

which gave me this output.

```
http://127.0.0.1:55969
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

Now opening the URL `http://127.0.0.1:55969` in a browser works.
[image: output image from browser]
Hope this helps!